# directive not interpolating, in a template string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to conditionally build a template. I got a k2plugin directive with some divs and spans. According to the pluginui attribute, I want to insert another directive at the end of the template. My code, that follows, interpolates everything but pluginui
For example, the last div results in:

```
<div {{pluginui}} width='300' height='420'></div>
```

{{pluginui}} is literal, while it should interpolate to trigger the other directive.
Funny thing is, if I put {{pluginui}} elsewhere in the same line (for example between the  tags, it gets interpolated.

What am I getting wrong?

```
app.directive("k2plugin", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: true,
                link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
                    console.log ("creating plugin");

                    // this won't work immediatley. attribute pluginname will be undefined as soon as this is called.
                    scope.pluginname = "Loading...";
                    scope.pluginid = null;

                    // observe changes to interpolated attributes

                            // [...] observe name, id, width, height

                    attrs.$observe('pluginui', function(value) {
                        console.log('pluginui has changed value to ' + value);
                        scope.pluginui = attrs.pluginui + "viewport";
                    });

                },
                template: "<div>\
                           <div>\
                           <span>{{pluginname}}</span>\
                           <span ng-click=\"resize(pluginid)\">_</span> <span ng-click=\"remove(pluginid)\">X</span>\
                           </div>\
                           <div {{pluginui}} width='{{pluginwidth}}' height='{{pluginheight}}'></div>\
                           </div>",
                replace: true,
            };
        });

        app.directive("canvasviewport", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: true,
                link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
                    console.log ("creating canvas viewport");
                },
                template: "<canvas width='{{pluginwidth}}' height='{{pluginheight}}'></canvas>",
                replace: true
            };
        });

        app.directive("divviewport", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: true,
                link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
                    console.log ("creating div viewport");
                },
                template: "<div style=\"width='{{pluginwidth}}' height='{{pluginheight}}'\"></div>",
                replace: true
            };
        });

        app.directive("autoviewport", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: true,
                link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
                    console.log ("creating auto viewport");
                },
                template: "<canvas width='{{pluginwidth}}' height='{{pluginheight}}'></canvas>",
                replace: true
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think Angular will interpolate something into a directive name.  {{}}s (automatically) set up a $watch.  When the $watch notices a change, it will update the view, but it won't call $compile, which is what I think needs to happen here.

So, I would try generating the HTML/template in the directive's link function and then $compile it.  Something like:

```js
scope.$watch('pluginui', function(newValue) {
   var jqLiteWrappedElement = angular.element('<div ' + newValue + ' width=...');
   element.replaceWith(jqLiteWrappedElement);
   $compile(jqLiteWrappedElement)(scope);
})
```

Remember to inject `$compile` into the directive.

Comment: If you need to change it in runtime very oftenly (what seems to a bad idea) you could create a directive that receives the interpolation as its argument (`<element dynamic="{{pluginui}}"`) and `$observe` it. Then change the element template and re`$compile` it. Otherwise, the best approach is to write the template as string  (like you did) and use `$interpolate` to add the tags, then `$compile` it. At least, interpolation does not work on tag structure, like attribute name, tag name and so on.

Comment: angularjs deals with DOM nodes and <div {{plugin}}> is not valid. You need to do what CaioToOn suggested or dynamic="pluginui" and watch the variable directly if it's more than a string

Comment: @Liviu, when I said "try generating the HTML in the link function", I meant something like `var html = '<div ' + scope.pluginui + ' width=...`.  I should have been more clear, so thanks.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: +1, though if I was the OP I'd consider a different way to enable functionality depending on what these plugins do. It might be that the recompile might be more costly than a simple switch statement that activates the plugin required. Always measure first and never micro optimize.

Comment: These plugins are inserted dynamically. width and height can change often, but pluginui is set only at insertion (only once, when a k2plugin element is inserted in the module and the link function is created). Since I don't know what pluginui will be before creating the element, I must observe for it at least once.

Comment: @LiviuT. what do you mean with "a simple switch statement that activates the plugin required"? Can you make an example? (I started using angular yesterday, I'm a real newbie : )