# Double indirection in data-binding. Interpolate string in a template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to resolve double binding in the link function of a directive:

```
scope.a = "surprise";
scope.b = "{{ a }}";
```

the template  is `<div>{{ b }}</div>`

it's rendered like `<div>{{ a }}</div>`

is it possible to get the view to display `<div>surprise</div>` ? 
I've been trying to recompile the directive, but once `b` is binded, contents are a string and angularJS won't attempt any more to bind them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original post is a simplification of my problem. Basically I had in the scope strings like `{{ foo }}` that had to be assigned to a variable in the template (for example, `{{ b }}` in the post), because the value is different depending on certain factors.

As @AjayBeniwal mentioned, a simple case is solved with a function. This is basically the same as

```js
function test($scope) {
    var foo = "surprise";
    $scope.b = function () {
       return foo;
    };
 }
```

but instead of `foo`, I got a property of the `scope` object and I interpolate on a function.

What I did instead is to watch for changes in the string. See [directive not interpolating, in a template string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485288/directive-not-interpolating-in-a-template-string)

```js
return {
    template: '<div class="caption">{{ caption }}</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
        scope.caption = fooService.computeCaption(); // here caption is set to a string '{{ bar }}'

        scope.$watch('caption', function(newValue) {
           scope.caption = newValue;
           $compile(element.contents())(scope); // resolve (interpolate?) the string `{{ bar }}`
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to interpolate on function rather then value directly

```
  function test($scope) {
              $scope.a = "surprise";
              $scope.b = function () {
                  return $scope.a;
              };

          }

 <div>{{ b() }}</div>
```

Comment: thanks! this is a good idea. because you mentioned interpolation I found a solution for what I need. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a custom filter that can interpolate values within the current scope.**

In your template: (`this` refers to the current scope)

```
{{ b | interpolate:this }}
```

The filter implementation is trivial:

```
app.filter('interpolate', function($interpolate) {
    return function(expression, context) {
        return $interpolate(expression)(context);
    };
});
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/gegeji/1/edit?html,js,output