# Interpolation of an interpolation for an attribute (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to allow the user to edit forms in an application, e.g. set the label of a field, but I want the user to enjoy to power of Angular's interpolation to create dynamic forms.

When it comes to labels this is easy, with a [costume directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

But when it comes to attributes, this is more difficult. Suppose I want to let the user set a relevance equation for a question, e.g. `movieRating.relevant='{{seenMovie===true}}'`.

I currently solve this by calling interpolate on the interpolated variable.

Template:

```
<div class="control-group" ng-show="interpolate('{{ movieRating.relevant }}')">
    <!--  field html -->
</div>
```

Directive/Controller:

```
scope.interpolate = function(text, mustHaveExpression, trustedContext) {
    $interpolate(text, mustHaveExpression, trustedContext)(scope)
}
```

I'm looking for a more Angular way to do it (something that would use `$compile` for instance).

Comment: is this similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945800/double-indirection-in-data-binding-interpolate-string-in-a-template

Comment: It's similar, but doesn't solve my problem because I want "double interpolation" for attributes and this does it for content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Angular [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter) that does the interpolation for you and can be reused anywhere:

```
angular
  .module(...)
  .filter(
    'interpolate',
    ['$parse', $parse => (name, scope) => $parse(name)(scope)]
  );
```

... then use it in your templates:

```
<div ng-show="movieRating.relevant | interpolate:this">
```

And voilà!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a pipe over it as proposed by **ccjmne**

```
<div ng-show="movieRating.relevant | interpolate:this">
```

I have detailed the code in the following example
Don't forget to exports & declare the pipe in a @NgModule

the html

```
<a [href]="this.$urlProjectDetails | interpolate:this" target="_blank">
```

The custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'interpolate' })
export class InterpolatePipe implements PipeTransform {

// {{ context.url | interpolate:this}}
transform(
    text    : string,
    scope   : object,
    props   : object = {} // OverWrite this
): string {
    return this.interpolate(
        text,
        scope,
        props
    )
  }


      interpolate(stringToInterpolate : string, scope : object, props : object = null) {

        var LOCAL = {
            oSource : scope,// should be = this
            value : null,
            foundValue  : true
        }
        return stringToInterpolate.replace(/\${(.*?)\}/g, function(match, expr : string) {

            //try props for the value
            LOCAL.value = props || {};
            expr.split('.').some( currentExpr=>{
                if(currentExpr in LOCAL.value){
                    LOCAL.value = LOCAL.value[currentExpr];
                    return false;
                } else {
                    LOCAL.foundValue = false;
                    LOCAL.value = '';
                    return true;// stop execution of array with some()
                }
            })

            //if we did not found a value in the given props, find it in the this scope
            if(!LOCAL.foundValue){
                LOCAL.value = LOCAL.oSource
                expr.split('.').some( currentExpr=>{
                    if(currentExpr in LOCAL.value){
                        LOCAL.value = LOCAL.value[currentExpr];
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        LOCAL.foundValue = false;
                        LOCAL.value = '';
                        return true;// stop execution of array with some()
                    }
                })
            }

            return LOCAL.value
        });
    };
}
```