# angular js: build directive tag in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a template I would like to do something like:

`<my-{{data.type}}></my-{{data.type}}>`

but it doesn't replace the `{{data.type}}` markup.

Is there a solution or a workaround for this?

Comment: No, you can't have dynamically defined tags/directives.

Comment: Just put your `type` in an attribute and use the `scope:{yourattr:'@'}` to make use if it in your directive.

Comment: several ways you can do it but more context would help

Comment: Your question is similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485288/directive-not-interpolating-in-a-template-string also there is a solution provided in the comments there

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that but you can use ng-switch like,

```
<div ng-switch="data.type">
  <div ng-switch-when="test1">
    <my-test1></my-test1>   
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="test2">
    <my-test2></my-test2>   
  </div>
</div>
```