# AngularJS Modify Scope in Directive Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angular directive:

```
app.directive('myStyle', function($location) {
  return {
    scope: {
      myCSSFile: "="
    },
    //template: '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />',
    template: '<link href="{{ myCSSFile }}.css" rel="stylesheet" />',
    link: function(scope,el, attr) {
      var absUrl = $location.absUrl();
      console.log(absUrl);

      if (absUrl == 'http://run.plnkr.co/KDRUOzkRgvgCzdzy/') {
        console.log("Found");
        scope.myCSSFile = 'style';
      }
      else {
        console.log("Not found");
        scope.myCSSFile = 'style2';
      }      
    }
  };
});
```

How do i bind a value to `{{ myCSSFile }}` within the template based on the function within my `link`?

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/I6om40ZfRZbETwsbl3MO?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15485288/3556874

Comment: @NaeemShaikh - thanks for the link, i get i have to set scope to true and use $complie... but how do i return jqLiteWrappedElement to the template? Also, there is a watch on pluginui i dont see that i actually need to watch anything for this as it will only ever be triggered on page load.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh - see this fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pp2PkRcHb07EqNweJJfR?p=preview

Comment: Updated the code without the .watch

Answer (score 1):

You can't use two way binding for `myCSSFile` with undefined value. So if you want isolated scope you can change it to bind with `@`, or create a new scope:

```
scope: true, // plunker1
scope: { // plunker2
    myCSSFile = '@'
},
```

[Punker1](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2ELfslA7wBPoL8LBi5q?p=preview) , [Plunker2](http://plnkr.co/edit/yo0lEkAq6hX2PEKHIsSp?p=preview)

Comment: your plunker link.. Its still showing as scope: true... no comment about scope: {
    myCSSFile = '@'
},

Comment: that's because you can use either one of them, i've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks... Although the output to the user is as expected, looking at the Network http requests, you can see errors: NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://run.plnkr.co/diEAdEJme62ZQgV8/%7B%7B%20myCSSFile%20%7D%7D.css"

Comment: i dont see 400.. i get cancelled status because `myCSSFile` was changed right after it was placed in the DOM. If you don't want that i guess you need to use $compile